# How to find magnetic field due to current in a circular loop of conducting wire at any arbitrary point in its plane?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

Consider a circular current loop of radius R in which a current enters at a point A and leaves at point B through straight wires. Minor arc AB subtends angle 'theta' at the centre of circle. Now at any point located at a distance r from the centre, how can the magnetic field be calculated?

Would it be zero? Because all the current entering the loop is leaving it, making net current zero(like in cases of symmetrical distribution around the centre of loop)?

I assume the Ampere's Law cannot be be applied because of non symmetrical nature. I also, Biot-Savart's law has the same problem.

And would the result hold in cases the point is on circumference of the loop?

(The whole system is considered in free space without any other force fields and wires are of negligle radius)

Comment: *Biot-Savart's law has the same problem.* Why do you think that? Did you try using it?

Comment: I tried. But I couldn't find a general equation that would include magnetic field due to all points of the coil. And how to integrate it. How should I tackle that?